# Fast Fourier function for image transformation Problems

Tags: java, image, fft

I have coded the following function to apply fast fourier transform on input image. I have got null pointer exception in line "F[2*k]= F[2*k].plus(w_ux.mul(f_even));".

1. Would anyone give any advice to me, please? [solved]
2. It takes quite a long time to finish running the transform, the time is similar to normal fourier transform. and the result image is not as expected.

```java
private Complex[] fft(byte[] img, int width, int height) {
    // M - height  N - width , u - height v - width
    Complex[] F = new Complex[width*height];  // one single point
    Complex w;
    int size = F.length;
    double w_ux_exp, w_u_exp;
    double f_even, f_odd;
    for (int u=0; u<size/2;u++){
        for (int k=0; k<size/2; k++){
            f_even = (double)(img[2*k]&0xFF)*Math.pow(-1, k);  // f(x) for even, centering
            f_odd = (double)(img[2*k+1]&0xFF)*Math.pow(-1, k);  // f(x) for odd, centering
            w_u_exp =-2.0 * Math.PI*2*(img[u]&0xFF) / size;
            w_ux_exp =-2.0 * Math.PI*(2*k)*(img[u]&0xFF) / size;  //even
            Complex w_ux = Complex.fromPolar(1, w_ux_exp);
            Complex w_u = Complex.fromPolar(1, w_u_exp);
            F[2*u]= F[2*u].plus(w_ux.mul(f_even)); 
            F[2*u+1]=F[2*u+1].plus(w_u.mul(f_odd));
        }
    }

    return F;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Complex[] F = new Complex[width*height];` initializes the array to be filled with `null` values. I guess you need to fill it with zeros before you start.

Comment: yes, thanks. After initializing them, I had solved the null pointer exception problem.

Comment: actually I have another problem, it's about the centering. Is it right to do it by " f_even = (double)(img[2*k]&0xFF)*Math.pow(-1, k);"? and I also find that my code is not functioning as it expects... the image does not change to what a fourier transform should look like.

Comment: Can you add your new problem to question?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my questions.